# Failed to check user certificate permissions in Kubernetes: "Y and X are both specified for kubernetes-admin. Y will override"

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, authorization, kubectl

I am trying to check the kubelet certificate permissions with `kubectl auth can-i` but it failed with the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# kubectl --certificate-authority=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --client-certificate=/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem --client-key=/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem auth can-i --list
Error in configuration:
* client-cert-data and client-cert are both specified for kubernetes-admin. client-cert-data will override.
* client-key-data and client-key are both specified for kubernetes-admin; client-key-data will override
```

I read the error, it writes that the some field will be override but I don't understand why I don't see the permissions or what I need to do in order to see, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to you cert and key definitions on your kubeconfig file. Which is by default in `~/.kube/config` if you didn't set it as env variable KUBECONFIG.

Because on your kubeconfig there are cert data for user kubernetes-admin

```
    - name: kubernetes-admin
      user:
        client-certificate-data: xxxx=
        client-key-data: xxx==
```

You can just comment out your users `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` on your kubeconfig file and try the command again.. I was getting the same error and it works when I put a comment.